# Permutation based on inclusion exclusion principle

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

There are 3 states and 3 students representing each state. In how many ways can 3 students be chosen such that at least one student is chosen from each state ?

I think that answer should be

9C3 - ((3C1)* (6C3) - (3C2)(3C3)) = 27

But the answer given is 26. I think that they are also subtracting 3C3*3C3. I don't think it's possible because when excluding 1 or 2 states, we can't add a case where 3 students are chosen by excluding 3 states because it is not possible.

Am I correct?

Comment: A better way of seeing why it is 27, is because if you need to pick three students so that at least one student is chosen from each state, then it must happen that EXACTLY one student is chosen from each state, and this can be done independently, whence the answer is $3^3 = 27$. I don't see why it is $26$ at all.

Comment: Yes, that's indeed a better way. I am trying to apply inclusion exclusion principle to problems so as to get a good grip over it.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion they have excluded the instance where the arrangement of the students is the same as the standard one (the one in the statement). Plus , you ran into a very complicated argument. Assume the state 1 has the students $a_1$ $b_1$ $c_1$, state 2 $a_2$ $b_2$ $c_2$ and state 3 $a_3$ $b_3$ $c_3$.
Now, assume the number of possible arrangements according to the question for the first 2 states is n. Notice that for the state 3 individually there are 3 possible choices: $a_3$ $b_3$ and $c_3$. So by now we obtain $3*n$ answers. We do the same reasoning for the first 2 states and notice that n=$3^2$, so the number of possibilities is $3^3=27$, but the official one is 26 excluding the one in the sentence.